# ¿Cómo calcular el tiempo de ejecución sin colocar el comando time?

Tags: python, c, bash, línea-de-comandos

He realizado dos códigos en *C* y *python* para identificar números primos, tengo que ejecutarlo en *bash* con un *for loop* hasta los 5 primeros números, todo bien hasta ahí, pero me piden calcular el tiempo de ejecución de ese ciclo *for* sin usar el comando `time`... entonces no se como calcularlo.

Les adjunto mi código en *bash* el nombre del archivo en *python* y *C* es primo.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "programa en C"
gcc primo.c -o primo
for ((i=0; i<=5;i=i+1))
do
    ./primo $i
done
echo "Programa en python "
for ((i=0; i<=5;i=i+1))
do
    python3 primo.py $i
done
```

Comment: Saludos compañero, alomejor te interesaria copiar el valor del tiempo UNIX antes de iniciar la funcion y compararlo con el valor UNIX final y conversarlo en segundos,minutos y horas.

Alomejor te inspira esto: https://www.it-swarm-es.com/es/c/como-obtengo-la-marca-de-tiempo-de-unix-en-c-como-int/1067992121/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El comando date te ofrece la opción `+%s` que devuelve los segundos que han pasado desde el primer día del año de 1970 hasta el momento preciso en el que usas el comando `date +%s`, y tenemos la opción `+%N` para los nanosegundos (un segundo = mil millones nanosegundos).
Calcularemos el tiempo de ejecución de tu programa en c con todos los 9 dígitos correspondientes a los nanosegundos:

```sh
#Obtenemos los segundos como punto de partida y usamos un formato +%s.%N 
#para agregar un punto decimal para despues restar.
declare -r TiempoInicial=$(date +%s.%N)
echo "programa en C"
gcc primo.c -o primo
for ((i=0; i<=5;i=i+1))
do
    ./primo $i
done
#Una vez se acaba el for podemos restar el tiempo actual con el tiempo 
#guardado antes de ejecutar el for y obtendremos el tiempo de ejecución.
declare -r TiempoFinal=$(date +%s.%N)
declare -r TiempoDeEjecucion=$(echo "$TiempoFinal-$TiempoInicial" | bc) 
echo "Transcurrieron $TiempoDeEjecucion segundos para el programa en c"
```

Eso debería darte algo como:

```
programa en C
Transcurrieron 3.005704120 segundos para el programa en c
```

Ahora lo haremos con el programa en python pero utilizando unicamente tres dígitos decimales correspondientes a los nanosegundos, esto nos facilitara leer mejor el tiempo transcurrido:

```sh
declare -r TiempoInicial=$(date +%s.%N)
echo "programa en Python"
for ((i=0; i<=5;i=i+1))
do
    python3 primo.py $i
done
declare -r TiempoFinal=$(date +%s.%N)
#Sabemos que los nanosegundos siempre son 9 dígitos y si queremos 
#solamente 3 entonces quitaremos los 6 últimos ya que 9 - 6 = 3
declare -r TiempoDeEjecucion=$(echo "$TiempoFinal-$TiempoInicial" | bc) 
echo "Transcurrieron ${TiempoDeEjecucion::-6} segundos para el programa en python"
```

Eso debería darte algo como:

```
programa en Python
Transcurrieron 3.006 segundos para el programa en python
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias en verdad tenia muchas dudas, super bien explicado gracias me has salvado, disculpa la poca experiencia